# mysql returning records that DO NOT MATCH query

Tags: mysql

`SELECT * FROM plugin_referral_code WHERE code=0;`

Returns this record

[image]

What!? Why?

Comment: number to string conversion? I forgot how it works, but I'm pretty sure it wouldn't happen if you used quotes around 0

Comment: @Sebas You're right it does not happen if I use a string. But why does this happen? The code does not match. It's a security vulnerability

Comment: My ORM doesn't wrap values in quotes if it doesn't have to. So if they put in the code 0, it'll send it as a number.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: Actually this link is not very helpful, sorry about it. I leave it because there are a few examples but they don't explain why or anything. Thjere must be something else somewhere else.

Comment: Your ORM is mistaken then. In this case it does need to because code is not an integer. What ORM is this and couldn't you force it as string for all codes entered? Even if you have codes set as string but could be interpreted as integer, the field is clearly a text field so you should be passing text exclusively

Comment: @KaiQing Codeigniter ActiveRecord. Yes, in this case I can ensure it's a string. But I'm worried about the rest of my codebase that's probably vulnerable... I knew people made fun of mysql, but now I understand why.

Comment: LOL I just googled "member login" and went to page 10. I put my username and password both as 0, and boom, I'm logged in. That's whack

Comment: lol... that's good. Way to go CI. I'd blame active record before mysql. If the ORM isn't covering all bases then they're first to blame. But I've heard war stories about mysql as well. Doesn't stop us from using it. You're screwed without a full audit of the concerned areas. At least active record is optional. If you had to manually write the queries in CI there's nothing stopping you. ORMs... love/hate. Good luck

Comment: The results are correct. Before assuming that it is incorrect, you should have tried "SELECT 'butts' = 0" to be sure that the condition is false.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not return an incorrect result for that query. Please, note that most important web sites use MySQL or its forks, so it is illogical to assume that a query like that doesn't work correctly.

You are comparing potatoes with tomatoes. 'butts' is a string, 0 is a number. MySQL (or any program ever existed) cannot compare strings to numbers. So, it internally converts 'butts' to a number. Any string, if converted to a number, is 0.

Also note that your client is ignoring a MySQL warning that explains the problem:

```
MariaDB [test]> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                   |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'butts' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I suggest to immediately uninstall any client that hides MySQL warnings... but this is a personal opinion :)

Answer (score -1):

Are you definitely executing the entire query in your query editor? I know some editors let you execute (highlighted) parts of queries. It's possible that if you're actually only executing `SELECT * FROM plugin_referral_code WHERE code` it would return any rows with non-NULL `code` values.

This is because the where clause needs to evaluate to true, and `WHERE code` would evaluate to true for any non-NULL `code` value.

That's all I can guess on this. If this is not the case, please provide more detail, e.g. what type column `code` is, and execute your query with `DESC` before it to get any query plan details.

Comment: I'm afraid that your answer is wrong. "SELECT 'butts' = 0" returns 1, and this is completely correct.

Comment: That wasn't what I was implying. I said if you run a query where that ends with `WHERE code` and no value (" = 0") it will return rows. I also asked for the column types, because that is relevant and you hadn't provided it.

Comment: I am not the author of this question. However, 'butts' is obviously a string (doesn't matter if it's char or varchar or other type), and 0 is a number. So, MySQL is correct, and there is no reason to suppose that only part of the query was executed :)

Comment: Also, I have a little correction: "WHERE code would evaluate to true for any non-NULL code value". But '' evaluates to false.